# Have sort() use culture info when sorting custom IComparable

Tags: c#, sorting, cultureinfo, icomparable

I have a class like this:

```
public class Item : IComparable
{
    public Type cType { get; set; }
    public object cData { get; set; }
    public Item(Type cType, object cData)
    {
        this.cType = cType;
        this.cData = cData;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;
        var otherItem = Convert.ChangeType(obj, cType);
        var ownItem = Convert.ChangeType(cData, cType);
        if (typeof(string) == cType)
        {
            var res = string.Compare((string)ownItem, (string)otherItem, false, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
            return res;
        }
        if (otherItem is IComparable cmp)
        {
            return cmp.CompareTo(ownItem);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and a List of this Item, like this:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
```

I know that there's some exception-handling missing here, but for the purpose of keeping this post short I'm leaving that out.
I need to sort this list by the cData in my Item, this is how I'm trying to do that:

```
Items.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y.cData)
```

This works fine for items not affected by Culture information, but if the cData is a string containing some culture specific characters the sorting goes wrong. For example: if I have this list of names (strings) in my list:

```
Tord
Viktor
Örjan 
Uno
```

and try to sort it, it returns:

```
Örjan
Tord
Uno
Viktor
```

this is wrong, the Swedish character 'ö' should appear last in the alphabet, and the expected outcome would be:

```
Tord
Uno
Viktor
Örjan
```

What am I doing wrong here? and how can I achieve the expected outcome?

**EDIT #1:**
the Comparison overload of .Sort() is needed as this function only acts as a part in an larger system that uses it. I should probably have said that in the original question.

Lets say that I have an other class looking like this:

```
public class ItemCollection
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Item> SortingValues;
        public string SomeColectionInfo;
    }
```

I got a List of this class, ItemCollection:

```
List<ItemCollection> AllCollections = new List<ItemCollection>();
```

Finally I got a function, that are to sort the collections based on the one values of the items that they are holding:

```
void SortCollectionsOn(string Attribute)
    {
        AllCollections.Sort((x, y) => (x.SortingValues.ContainsKey(Attribute) ? x.SortingValues[Attribute] : new Item(typeof(string), "")).CompareTo(y.SortingValues.ContainsKey(Attribute) ? y.SortingValues[Attribute] :""));
    }
```

I need to use the overload for this to work as some items don't have the attribute i'm sorting on.

this way I can sort on a attribute existing in a item. This is working until culture info is introduced. I didn't include this in my original question as i suspect that the problem lays in the cultural info.

Comment: Can you get/set the culture before executing this code and see if you are executing with the expected culture?

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken yes, doing this gives the same results, also if i break on CompareTo and check the culture it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the function **String.Compare()** where not returning the correct result with the parameters given in the above question. Adding an CompareOption solved this problem. By adding **CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase** the expected results are returned.

this is what the line should look like:

```
var res = String.Compare((Data.ToString()), (otherItem.Data.ToString()), _culture, CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```